# Can I pull a column from a query into a table based upon a condition in MSAccess

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I use Access 2010 and have been trying to resolve this issue for a while now.  My query is as follows and I get an "Operation must use an updateable query" error.

```
UPDATE ServiceDetRules SET DuplicateOf = (SELECT ID FROM ServiceDetRulesDuplicates WHERE ServiceDetRules.[ServiceID] = ServiceDetRulesDuplicates.[ServiceID])
WHERE (SELECT NumberOfDups from ServiceDetRulesDuplicates) IS NOT NULL;
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

On the design tab, change the query type to UPDATE

Answer (score 0):

First, Access (ACE, Jet, whatever) does not support a subquery in the `SET` clause, even though the SQL-92 Standard allows it. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231350/operation-must-use-an-updatable-query-error-3073-microsoft-access/1238335#1238335) for details (in case it's not clear, Access forces you to use its proprietary `UPDATE..JOIN..SET` syntax and you must re-write your `UPDATE` statement accordingly).

Second, your `WHERE` clause looks suspect because a subquery returns rows rather than a scalar value. Here's a sugegsted fix:

`WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NumberOfDups FROM ServiceDetRulesDuplicates);`

---

Try something like:

```
UPDATE ServiceDetRules 
       INNER JOIN ServiceDetRulesDuplicates 
          ON ServiceDetRules.[ServiceID] = ServiceDetRulesDuplicates.[ServiceID]    
   SET ServiceDetRules.[DuplicateOf] = ServiceDetRulesDuplicates.[ServiceID];
```

Comment: So I need to figure out what join to use?  I tried doing it this way and it gave me the same error.
 ... 
UPDATE ServiceDetRules INNER JOIN ServiceDetRulesDuplicates ON ServiceDetRules.[ServiceID] = ServiceDetRulesDuplicates.[ServiceID] SET ServiceDetRules.[DuplicateOf] = (SELECT ID FROM ServiceDetRulesDuplicates) WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NumberOfDups from ServiceDetRulesDuplicates);

Comment: @PayDay Pat: See updated answer but I'm not really au fait with Access proprietary syntax.

Comment: Still the same issue.  What exactly does it need to be an updateable query?

Comment: @PayDay Pat: Is `ServiceDetRulesDuplicates` a 'totals query' i.e. involves a SQL set function such as `MAX()` or (ahem) `LAST()`? If so you are out of luck: [Update Query Based on Totals Query Fails](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/116142). Access's lack of support for SQL-92 `UPDATE` syntax is it's worst bug (and makes it unfit for purpose) IMO.